# Locking viewport to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I've been developing a website and I was wondering if there was a way to lock the view port to a div, so that when you scroll down it automatically scrolls to the next section instead of you scrolling past it and then it locks until you scroll again?

So I've taken into account what people have suggested and now I have this as my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var lastScroll = 0;
    var posNum = 1;
    var currentDiv = "#view";
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScroll){
            posNum = posNum + 1;
            if (posNum > 6) {
                posNum = 6;
            }
            currentDiv = currentDiv + posNum;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(currentDiv).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
        else {
            posNum = posNum - 1;
            if (posNum < 1) {
                posNum = 1;
            }
            currentDiv = currentDiv + posNum;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(currentDiv).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
        lastScroll = st;
    });
});
```

But now I'm getting an error saying cannot read property 'top' property undefined, it only works on the first use of the website (on refresh).

Comment: You must make all your divs `100vw` and `100vh` and attach a scroll handler which moves from one div to another based on whether delta is positive or negative.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use an array for the id's of the divs, and then cycle through those as you scroll? So you increment or decrease the delta then it cycles through the array to soft scroll to the element?

Comment: You necessarily don't need to maintain an array if you standardize the `id` of each div, say `view1`, `view2` and in general `viewn`. Just maintain the current view index in a local variable.